# What protocol does VMware ESXi Remote Console use?

Tags: vmware-esxi

What is the protocol used by VMware ESXi to enable vSphere client's Remote Console to view and control the VMs?

Is it "VMware Remote Console" or "PCoIP"?

Is there any way to control the VMs through a web interface (i.e. not vSphere client)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's VMware Remote Console and it runs over TCP port 903. It is only available by using the vSphere client to connect to an ESX(i) host or vCenter server.

PCoIP is used by VMware View, not ESX(i)/vSphere.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to control the VMs
>   through a web interface (i.e. not
>   vSphere client)?

Yes. VMWare ESXi and vSphere both come with web portals, accessible on the IP address of the individual ESXi servers or the vSphere IP (if you have configred them correctly).

You can do a reasonably amount of stuff, but I don't think you can access the consoles of your guests. You can see VMWare's [documentation about it here](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r40/vsp_40_web_access.pdf).